# Error handling and saving error in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a for loop that is iteration through a column and doing some xml processing. There are some errors that I am encountering, but rather than just pass them, I would like to save them into a seperate list as part of the output. This is what I have so far:

```
def outputfunc(column_name):
    output = []
    errors = []
    for i in column_name:
        try:
            tree = etree.fromstring(i)
        except:
            errors.append(i) #basic logic here is that i append errors with i that raise error and then pass
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on Carcigenicates comment, if you want to find all errors using the `Exception` base class, you can change your code to:

```
def outputfunc(column_name):
    output = []
    errors = []
    for i in column_name:
        try:
            tree = etree.fromstring(i)
        except Exception as e:
            errors.append(e) #basic logic here is that i append errors with i that raise error and then pass
```

This sets `e` to the text of the error message. `e` is then appended to errors. Furthermore, I've removed a nonfunctional `pass` statement. However, you currently have no way to output errors, so I suggest using

```
print('\n'.join(map(str,errors)))
```

Within the scope of outputfunc. Furthermore, as Paul Cornelius suggests, returning your output and errors in tuple format would be useful. This would make your code

```
def outputfunc(column_name):
    output = []
    errors = []
    for i in column_name:
        try:
            tree = etree.fromstring(i)
        except Exception as e:
            errors.append(e) #basic logic here is that i append errors with i that raise error and then pass
    print('\n'.join(map(str,errors)))
    return output, errors
```

**References**

[2. Lexical analysis — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

[Built-in Exceptions — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Comment: An improvement for sure.  But I think you should add `return output, errors` as the last line of the function.  As it stands it doesn't do anything useful since `output` is local and just gets thrown away.  I also think it would be better to let the calling code do the printing, in case it wants to do something else with the errors.